# allowing users to import kml to nokia location app

Tags: html, kml, kmz, here-api

I was just wondering if it was possible to allow users to open or load their own KML/KMZ files into a mobile html5 version of Here Maps and have them activate or deactivate a kml layer via the layers button included in the api?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that is possible at the moment. The **addLayer()** method can be used to add an overlay as shown below, but it isn't set up to read KML. If you're looking at loading KML you're probably going to be better off using the Maps API for JavaScript as shown in this example http://developer.here.net/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/data-visualization/display-data-on-map.html

Alternatively you could look into the [jHERE](http://jhere.net/) library, which does expose KML support from the underlying library.

Since the Mobile HMTL5 library doesn't offer a  polyline implementation, it would be difficult to add a KML route to the map, but it may be possible to load the data of a set of markers using the JavaScript library and then add the markers using the **addPOI()** method, but this would seem to be rather convoluted.

Here is a working overlay based on a button press:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=100">
    <!-- Definitions of mobile-friendly documents e.g. for BlackBerry: -->
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <!-- Definitions of mobile-friendly documents for Microsoft Browser: -->
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width">
    <!-- iOS viewport definitions: -->
    <!--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- disable BlackBerry UI events -->
    <meta name="touch-event-mode" value="native">
    <meta name="cursor-event-mode" value="native">
    <!-- disables address sniffing -->
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://api.maps.nokia.com/mobile/latest/lib/mh5.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://api.maps.nokia.com/mobile/latest/lib/colors.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
        .mh5_ProgressBar {
            width: 300px;
            left: 20px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .mh5_Map {
            height: auto;
            -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            -ms-flex:         1 0 auto;
            box-flex:         1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="mapContainer" style="height: 480px; width: 320px;"></div>

        <script src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/mobile/1.0.0/lib/mh5.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
           nokia.mh5.assetsPath = "../../lib/";
        nokia.mh5.appId = "demo_wwzrmoloHAFVvyW";
        nokia.mh5.appCode = "Vgl_08RQWnjJo92Lw1F_uQ";

        var progressObject,
            page = new nokia.mh5.ui.Page({
                children: ["controls",  "map"],
                layout: {
                    type: nokia.mh5.ui.RowLayout
                },
                visible: true,
                controls: {
                    control: nokia.mh5.ui.Container,
                    children: [ "show" ],
                    layout: {
                        type: nokia.mh5.ui.ColumnLayout
                    },

                    show: {
                        control: nokia.mh5.ui.Button,
                        text: "Show",
                        disabled: false,
                        onClick: function() {
                            page.map.addLayer(oldBerlin, "OLD_BERLIN");
                        }
                    }
                },

                map: {
                    control: nokia.mh5.components.Map,
                    center: {
                        longitude: 13.405,
                        latitude: 52.515
                    },
                    //enable either box or zoom
                    zoom: 13,
                    schema: "normal.day"
                }
            });

        document.body.appendChild(page.root);



      var oldBerlin = function(column,row,z){
        var zoom = 0;

        while (z > 1){
                zoom++;
                z = z /2;
        }

        if (((zoom == 12) &&  ( row != 1343  || column != 2200))||
            ((zoom ==13) &&  ( row < 2686 || column < 4400 || row >   2687 || column > 4401 ))||
            ((zoom == 14) &&  ( row <  5372 || column < 8800 || row >   5375 || column > 8803  ))||
            ((zoom  == 15)  &&  ( row  < 10744 || column < 17601 || row >   10750 || column > 17607 ))) {
                return "http://developer.here.net/apiexplorer/examples/res/old_berlin_overlay_tiles/blank.png";
        }

        return "http://developer.here.net/apiexplorer/examples/res/old_berlin_overlay_tiles/"+ zoom + "/"+ row+ "/" + column + ".png";
     };


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```